# Accessing sharepoint image library from PPT to autimatically add images in a PPT

Tags: powerpoint

Wondering if there is a way to link the asset/image library from SharePoint to PPT. This way when creating a presentation, I could click on the image library and it will right away give me the images saved in that library in SharePoint where I can choose an image from. Those images would already be vetted and proper copy protection given. I would also be able to embed videos or audios when needed from this SharePoint asset library.

Comment: We are in 2021 and I still cannot find an obvious way to do this.
Have you found a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by clicking on "Insert" -> "Pictures".

Now on the file select dialog enter the SharePoint library URL something like

```
https://webapp/sites/site/SiteAssets/
```

Press enter, this will forward you for authentication and then display all the files from the library. Your sign on information will be retained for the session so that you will be able to add files without sign in.

Comment: Thank you Amal....I am sorta new to sharepoint and trying to understand it better. How do I establish a connection between sharepoint and office? is that still possible? I heard this was taken away with the new releases. I did what you said above and it said path does not exist. Thanks.

Comment: Open the site assets library in browser. Then copy the URL and try insert pictures -> and paste the URL. Then office will try to make a connection to the Server.

Comment: yep no it's not working. I did that already....thank you for your help. I'll have ITS have a look.

Comment: Is there a way to add this as location/bookmark in the File dialog, or do I have to copy/paste the  SharePoint library URL each time?